# Examples of not-full functors between two categories in both directions?

Tags: category-theory, functors, hom-functor

A functor F:C→D from a category C to a category D is said to be full if, for each pair of objects, x,y ∈ C, the function,

F:C(x,y)→D(F(x),F(y))

between hom sets is surjective.

What I am unsure about is, for categories C and D, can you have a functor that is *not full* in both directions? That is, a category F:C→D and G:D→C, such that both F and G are not full.

In particular, are there any simple examples of this?

Comment: There are a gazillion examples of this. Given any categories $C$ and $D$ and an object $d$ of $D$, there is a functor $F : C \to D$ that maps every object of $C$ to $d$ and every morphism of $C$ to $\mathrm{id}_d$. This functor will only be full if $D$ if $d$ has no non-trivial endomorphisms.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest example: Let $C = D$ be the category with one object $x$ and two arrows $\text{id}_x$ and $f$ such that $f\circ f=\text{id}_x$. (This is the cyclic group of order $2$ viewed as a category.) Let $F=G\colon C\to C$ be the functor sending $x$ to $x$ and both arrows to $\text{id}_x$.